# What countries restrict liquids being carried through security at airports?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

Being from the United States, I had been under the impression that the "no liquids greater than a tiny amount" rule was fairly standard. Then I started flying in Asia and found that this was not the case. Flying both domestically and internationally in Indonesia, Myanmar, Thailand, Laos, Cambodia, and Malaysia, this restriction simply did not exist.

So, which countries or regions restrict a passenger from bringing liquids through security?

Comment: (Also if this is a duplicate, I apologize. I'm on mobile, which has much restricted dupe search functionality.)

Answer (score 8):

ANA [New restrictions on liquids, gels and aerosols as carry-on baggage](https://www.ana.co.jp/topics/notice070423_e/index_e.html) lists these:

- United States
- Canada
- United Kingdom
- EU
- Japan
- Singapore
- South Korea
- Taiwan
- Hong Kong
- Vietnam
- China
- Indonesia
- Philippines
- Myanmar
- India
- Thailand

Comment: And yet I hauled a liter bottle of water through Indonesian security about two months ago, so I'm extremely skeptical of the accuracy of said list.

Comment: The UK is (still) in the EU...

Comment: What the UK does security wise deserves a separate entry.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I also "smuggled" (by accident! I swear!) a water bottle on multiple flights within the European Union. Sometimes they simply don't check properly (which makes the whole thing rather pointless...)

Comment: @dirkk ... I stuck the bottle directly on the belt. No trying to hide. Also all of the posters showing cartoons of banned goods and other rules (eg removal of laptops from bags) made no mention of liquids.

Comment: That list of countries doesn't look a whole lot different to the countries ANA flies to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Nippon_Airways_destinations

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: I once had a friend (unintentionally) passing through security with a 1.5L bottle full of water (in his hand luggage), whilst the guy behind him was stopped for having a small 0.5L bottle partially filled in his backpack. Was your bottle visible and were there signs about liquid transport restrictions?

Comment: @MatthieuM The bottle went through the scanner by itself, not inside any luggage or in a bin with other things. There were plenty of posters about restricted items, but none made any mention of liquids.

Comment: Ok now I have proof that this list is incomplete. As mentioned in an above comment it seems ANA only listed the subset of countries that it actually flies to. I just flew through Ukraine (Kiev) and Moldova (Chișinău) and in both places the 100ml restriction was in place, and neither is on the list (nor does ANA fly there AFAIK.)